# Merging two df One to Many within List - R

Tags: r

To start I will ignore the use of lists and show what I want using two df's.

I have `df1`

```
ID    v1    Join_ID
1     100     1
2     110     2
3     150     3
```

And `df2`

```
Join_ID    Type    v2
1          a       80
1          b       90
2          a       70
2          b       60
3          a       50
3          b       40
```

I want the `df.join` to be:

```
ID     v1    Join_ID    a_v2    b_v2
1      100       1       80      90
2      110       2       70      60
3      150       3       50      40
```

I have tried:

```
df.merged <- merge(df1, df2, by="Join_ID")
df.wide <- dcast(melt(df.merged, id.vars=c("ID", "type")), ID~variable+type)
```

But this repeats all the variables in df1 for each type: `v1_a v1_b`

On top of this I have two lists

```
list.1
df1_a
df1_b
df1_c

list.2
df2_a
df2_b
df2_c
```

And I want the `df1_a` in list 1 to join with the `df2_a` in list 2

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with `map`ing through the `list` elements and then do the join

```
library(tidyverse)
map2(list.1, list.2, ~ 
           .y %>%
              mutate(Type = paste0(Type, "_v2")) %>%
              spread(Type, v2) %>% 
              inner_join(.x, by = 'Join_ID'))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:3, v1 = c(100L, 110L, 150L), Join_ID = 1:3), 
   .Names = c("ID", 
"v1", "Join_ID"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L
))

df2 <- structure(list(Join_ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), Type = c("a", 
"b", "a", "b", "a", "b"), v2 = c(80L, 90L, 70L, 60L, 50L, 40L
)), .Names = c("Join_ID", "Type", "v2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

list.1 <- list(df1_a = df1, df1_b = df1, df1_c = df1)
list.2 <- list(df2_a = df2, df2_b = df2, df2_c = df2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Some replies to your request : 
 
     1. the reshaping of df2 
 
     2. the join with different column names

library(reshape2)

```
    df1=data.frame(id=c(1,2,3), v1=c(100,110,150))
    df2=data.frame(Join_ID=c(1,1,2,2,3,3),Type=c("a","b","a","b","a","b"),v2=c(80,90,70,60,50,40))

    cast_df2=dcast(df2, Join_ID ~ Type)
    mergedData <- full_join(df1,cast_df2, by=c("id"="Join_ID"),suffixes=c("_df1","_df2") )
```